# Android Kotlin - picasso refresh / invalidate cached image from URL

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

This is the code I'm using to show an image:

```
Picasso.get().load(profileImgUrl).transform(CircleTransform()).into(profileUserImage)
```

Now I want to refresh it when this image changes on the server

I tried:

```
Picasso.get().load(profileImgUrl).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).transform(CircleTransform()).into(profileUserImage)
```

and also

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).invalidate(profileImgUrl)
```

As suggested in countless answers but `with` isn't working any more so I tried

```
Picasso.get().invalidate(profileImgUrl)
```

All of this isn't working and I don't want to use the stupid workaround with adding milliseconds or anything to the image URL but just refresh it how it suppose to be possible!

Comment: Have you printed out the url ? Is the url different?

Comment: It's not different otherwise it wouldn't show old cached image

Comment: are you using firebase database

Comment: Nope. I have switched picasso with glide now